# Binding checked menu items to ViewModel commands

Tags: wpf, xaml, command, menuitem, ischecked

I have in XAML 3 menu items defined (using WPF-MDI):

```
<MenuItem Header="_Generic" Name="Generic" ToolTip="Generic Visual Studio designer theme" 
          Command="{Binding Path=SelectGenericTheme}"/>
<MenuItem Header="_Luna" Name="Luna" ToolTip="Blue Windows XP theme"
          Command="{Binding Path=SelectLunaTheme}"/>
<MenuItem Header="_Aero" Name="Aero" ToolTip="Windows Vista/7 theme" 
          Command="{Binding Path=SelectAeroTheme}"/>
```

And the definitions of the commands and current selection in the ViewModel:

```
    public enum ESelectedTheme
    {
        Generic,
        Luna,
        Aero
    }

    ESelectedTheme _selectedTheme;

    ICommand _selectGenericThemeCommand;
    public ICommand SelectGenericThemeCommand
    {
        get { return _selectGenericThemeCommand ?? (_selectGenericThemeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => SelectGenericTheme(), 
            param => true)); }
    }

    void SelectGenericTheme()
    {
        _selectedTheme = ESelectedTheme.Generic;
    }


    ICommand _selectLunaThemeCommand;
    public ICommand SelectLunaThemeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectLunaThemeCommand ?? (_selectLunaThemeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => SelectLunaTheme(),
                param => true));
        }
    }

    void SelectLunaTheme()
    {
        _selectedTheme = ESelectedTheme.Luna;
    }


    ICommand _selectAeroThemeCommand;
    public ICommand SelectAeroThemeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectAeroThemeCommand ?? (_selectAeroThemeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => SelectAeroTheme(),
                param => true));
        }
    }

    void SelectAeroTheme()
    {
        _selectedTheme = ESelectedTheme.Aero;
    }
```

I have 2 questions (hope that is allowed inside one post):

1. I want to bind the IsChecked property in XAML to the value that is selected (_selectedTheme). I think I need to write a converter but I don't know how.
2. I made 3 copies of ICommands (one for each theme) ... what if I would have 20 themes ... is there a way to make this code parameterized?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can specify a [`CommandParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.commandparameter.aspx) and you ask about how to parameterize a command? Have you always been ignoring the `param => ...` without wondering how to use that?

Comment: With parameterize I mean to have instead of 3 commands only using 1 command (but I will check how CommandParameter works, maybe that helps). Thanks for the comment.

Comment: With `RelayCommand(T)` it's pointless to pass in 'true' as the Predicate because it is defaulted that way to begin with.

Comment: @m-y: Depends on the implementation...

Comment: @H.B. I guess there might be one blog out there that posts a version of `RelayCommand(T)` with only one constructor taking both parameters, but the top google searches all allow for just `Action(T)` to be passed in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will not be necessary to parameterize the command as the binding will do everything but as noted it would be possible using `CommandParameter`. Here the converter will get the enum parameter.

An example:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Description" IsCheckable="True"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=DisplayMode_Current,
                            Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConv},
                            ConverterParameter=Description}" />
<MenuItem Header="_Web-Page" IsCheckable="True"
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=DisplayMode_Current,
                            Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConv},
                            ConverterParameter=WebPage}" />
```

The converter can look something like this:

```cs
public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // You could also directly pass an enum value using {x:Static},
        // then there is no need to parse
        string parameterString = parameter as string;
        if (parameterString == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        if (Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) == false)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        object parameterValue = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), parameterString);

        return parameterValue.Equals(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string parameterString = parameter as string;
        if (parameterString == null)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return Enum.Parse(targetType, parameterString);
    }
}
```

As the XAML is still verbose (and redundant!) you could take it further by binding the `ItemsSource` of the parent `MenuItem` to the enum values and then work with the `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: I guess SelectedTheme (the property in the ViewModel) should be a dependencyproperty? If so ... I have still to learn a lot about WPF.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: No, never use dependency properties in a VM, you know [INPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and [how to implement it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx), right? It should just be a normal property implementing that interface for binding notifications.

Comment: Yes I'm using that ... than I have to check my code again since I don't see the enumeration value being changed after changing the menu item ... probably my fault ... It's quite hard to debug XAML code.

Comment: [No, it's not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

Comment: I think I learn a lot today(night) about XAML ... thanks for the info.

Comment: I think there should still be some Commmand= binding in the XAML code you provided. Currently only the IsCheckable and IsChecked  and Header properties are set, but what happens if I select the menu item itself (to change the value?)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: The property you bound to will be changed, all MenuItems - as they all bind to it - will then update and thus be unchecked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7872/discussion-between-michel-keijzers-and-h-b)